# save settings with customize when running --no-init-file option

Tags: emacs

I'm running my own emacs config that resides in non-default place. So I use `-Q -l` startup options. I've defined place for saving customization and set custom-file variable accordingly.

Unfortunately emacs refuses to save my custom options motivating it with possible harm to original options. But I know what I do, and I what to have separate custom file filled with current session variables?

How can I overcome emacs restrictions?

emacs manual says:

> If Emacs was invoked with the -q or --no-init-file options (see Initial Options), it will not let you save your customizations in your initialization file. This is because saving customizations from such a session would wipe out all the other customizations you might have on your initialization file.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `-Q`. That implies `-q`, and I trust that if your config resides elsewhere, you do *not* also have any of the default init filenames for Emacs to find and use.

Instead, use the combination of options that you actually need. Refer to:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Initial Options` <kbd>RET</kbd>

```
`-Q'
`--quick'
     Start emacs with minimum customizations.  This is similar to using
     `-q', `--no-site-file', `--no-site-lisp', and `--no-splash'
     together.  This also stops Emacs from processing X resources by
     setting `inhibit-x-resources' to `t' (*note Resources::).
```

**Edit:**

I'm really not sure I understand why you need to retain your default init files when you claim that you don't want to use them. It would help if you clarified why `--no-init-file` is critical? Are you trying to provide a secondary configuration of Emacs which does not conflict with how people usually run it?

You might work around it by setting the `HOME` environment variable in your start-up script.
See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Find Init` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Also see the `init-file-user` variable and, for the gory details, the `command-line` function.

(Perhaps setting the likes of `init-file-user`, `user-init-file`, & `custom-file` with `--eval` might work.)

Comment: `--no-site-file --no-init-file --no-site-lisp --no-splash` are still needed for my installation. All initialization is performed from startup script. The only spare option from `-Q` is `inhibit-x-resources`. And `--no-init-file` is very essential for me, so I'm need it and need to overcome stupid emacs limitation